# how to set subdomain for length of integration test on multi-site app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, integration-testing

what's the best way to change a subdomains for the duration of an integration test?

jamis buck suggested using host! here:
http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/3/9/integration-testing-in-rails-1-1#12

but according to the rails API, host! only changes the host for the following single request.  i'm looking for something like @request.host in a functional test, which lets me use the subdomain for the entire test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using **host!** in my integration tests without a problem.  I generally call it once in the **setup** method, e.g.

```
def setup
    host! "my.host"    
end
```

Comment: thanks.  i was running into an unrelated error - host! works.